# JS. Чем плох for in?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Чего-то раньше думал, что `for in` - это так себе правильно.. А тут еще увидел такое в статье:

> Добавлены методы `Object.values()` и `Object.entries()`, который дополняют
>   уже стандартизированный метод `Object.keys` и позволяют получить массив
>   из значений или связок ключ/значение для хранящихся в объекте
>   перечисляемых данных (позволяет раскрыть содержимое ассоциативного
>   массива без перебора в `for in`).

Так вот вопрос - нужно ли использовать `for in`, или это я сам запутался?